# Does phpseclib checking SSH fingerprints?

Tags: ssh, fingerprint, phpseclib

Long time ago, phpseclib was not checking SSH fingerprints. Does phpseclib now implement checking SSH fingerprints?

Answer (score 0):

phpseclib has always had the ability to check fingerprints via the `$ssh->getServerPublicHostKey()` method. That method verifies that the host key is valid for the host and, if so, returns the host key for you to either save locally (be it to the DB or filesystem or whatever) or to check against the host key that you already have on file.

phpseclib has had this since the first release (0.1.0), which was over 10 years ago:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/0.1.0/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L1586
https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/0.1.0/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L745

In the initial release the signature would be checked regardless of whether or not you retrieved the host key. Now, the signature is only checked if you retrieve the host key.

That said, phpseclib's Crypt_RSA class didn't always have a getPublicKeyFingerprint() method:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/1.0.10/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php#L1850

Maybe that's what you're thinking of but if so that's completely irrelevant. The reason they exist is because of the following scenario:

You connect to a server, get the host public key and create a finger print from that. You call the operator of the server up and check your finger print with them. In the case of a 1024-bit RSA key it's more convenient to read someone 32 hexadecimal characters than it is to read someone 256 hexadecimal characters.

But then again, do you see yourself actually physically calling up the operator of an SSH server anyway?